# How do we call a point, or input size, for which it's worth to switch algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

It is known that lower time complexity doesn't necessarily mean faster execution. Sometimes, for a smaller input size, we can choose an algorithm that has a greater time complexity, but is faster for that input size.
How do we call a point, or input size, for which it's worth to switch algorithm in order for a program to execute quicker? Is it even something that was called in technical literature?

Comment: "Inflection point"?

Comment: Interesting question, I have no idea. I would call it "threshold" in English, but I don't know about the technical literature. This question is not a very good fit for Stack Overflow, it's a bit too theoretical. I don't think it's off-topic (see the [help/on-topic]) but you may still get more relevant eyes on our sister site [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), make sure to read their [help center](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there =)

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard terminology for this. Related concepts in mathematics and science include those already given (inflection point, threshold), ones similar to those already given (critical point, horizon, domain, discontinuity, etc.), and maybe other ways of viewing the same phenomenon (vertices, crossing points, intersections, zones, phases, stats, etc.). Again, I am not aware of any terminology for this except possibly the generic "interval" (intending literally the set of numbers being considered).

Comment: "Tipping point"?

Comment: I think there is no standard term, even in academic literature; a quick Google search yields textbooks and journal articles using the terms "cutoff" or "threshold". "Inflection point" in mathematics doesn't mean a point at which one thing crosses or overtakes another, so I doubt that is widely used for this.